# how to compare textfield string with array string in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

how to compare textfield string with array string in iphone sdk?
please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Google",@"AJS"];

NSString *tempString=textField.text;

for(int i=0; i<=[array count]; i++)
{
     if([tempString isEqualToString:[array objectAtIndex:i]])
     {
          NSLog("String is equal");
     }
}
```

this one will help you.